# Have anyone tried exporting alfresco developer framework component to web component and use it in react js application?

Tags: alfresco

As a cots product I am trying to evaluate Alfresco for my specific requirement. I already have one react application which is running. I want to leverage component which Alfresco developer framework(ADF). The problem those are angular component. Have any one tried using these ADF angular component in react?

Comment: It ought to work just fine - [does this Alfresco sample React application](https://github.com/Alfresco/adf-examples/tree/master/ADF_2.0.0/javascript-api/react) show you what you need to know about combining React with ADF?

Comment: This mentioned project is using js-api, my requirement is to export already available component in ADF as web component, since angular 6 is supports this feature and use it in react project.